# Does Apple require loading screen to be present on the application for iOS?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Does Apple require loading screen to be present on the application for the App Store? Standard black screen looks fine too.

Comment: You mean the `Default` image used during app launch?

Comment: Standard black screens don't look good, they just look like a bug or oversight, or like a "we really don't care about our app" message to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1): "Launch image **required** for all apps."